# How to fit a webpage to different screen sizes without disturbing its original width?

Tags: javascript

I was flirting with an idea of making a bookmark app which might let users bookmark only a section of a page like in this image. They will click twice on the page to mark two horizontal lines. Area between these lines will be highlighted to show the selected portion of the page.

I will be saving the y-coordinates of the two lines. That's it.

[image: selected portion of the webpage]

But what if:

1. The user opens the bookmark in a bigger or smaller screen afterwards. The webpage will re-size to fit the new width and some of the elements will definitely change their position. Then the coordinates will mismatch and wont show the original selected area.
2. The page content on the url changes later on.
3. The webpage is responsive. Then the mobile view will be completely different. It might not contain some of the elements from the original normal monitor screen.

Solution for problem 2 can be that we save a permanent copy of the page and then set coordinates on it. I have figured out this part of saving the webpage to a single html file which looks very much like the original.

And for 1 and 3 points I am thinking if it can be possible to somehow fix the width of the webpage to show against the screen width. i.e. just stretch or shrink the original page width according to the screen width. Is there a way to do this? I did some experimentation with viewport meta tag but it didn't work.

Do you guys have any idea? Anything else according to you that can go wrong? Any extra add-on?

Comment: Just liked the idea of bookmarking only a section of a long page for reference.

Comment: I think the best you can do is bookmark a tag. `<p class="markable" ondclick="bookmark()">Some Content.....`

Comment: That will only bookmark just a single point on the page. I would like to select section between two points.